# Node/NestJs: How to inject a class from within a method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, eventemitter

**manage-document.service.ts**

```
WorkflowApprovalCallback(){
 //subscribing to workflow event
 this.makeAnEntryInDb(); // this is undefined
}
 makeAnEntryInDb(){ //another function in same class}
```

**workflow.service.ts**

```
someWorkflowMethod(){
  event.emit(data);
}
```

Both are in different classes and different modules. They are in no way related.
The problem is that when workflow service's `someWorkflowMethod()` is invoked it emits an event.
This is event is being listened to by the manage document service's `WorkflowApprovalCallback()`. I want to call  `makeAnEntryInDb()` but then we do not have an instance of manage-document so `this` is `undefiend`.

If I create a new instance of  manage-document class with new keyword I will have to manually create and provide the constructor dependencies. Also it may create multiple instances of `manage-document`
How can I provide manage-document context or what is the correct way of doing it?

I can not import manage-document service in workflow because there could be a lot of such services that may need to be imported in workflow. I want to keep workflow independent. Not having to make any changes anytime there is a new service.

Comment: are declaring  makeAnEntryInDb function as static one?

Comment: We need to see more code context to understand how these are declared and how they are called.

Comment: @Youba um no its not static.